# How to characterize two definitions of conditional expectation for random variables.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation, causality

We can see conditional independence for $D$ and $Y$ given $X$ means $E[D\mid Y,X]=E[D\mid X]$ or $E[Y\mid D,X]=E[Y\mid X]$ in the causal analysis. However, by Wiki the conditional independence is defined as $E[YD\mid X]=E[Y\mid X]E[D\mid X]\ a.e.$.

I cannot bridge these definitions. Is one of them stronger than the other one?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Proof_in_the_general_case) that for sigma algebras $\mathcal{G}_1 \subset \mathcal {G_2} \subset \mathcal{F}$,
$$ E[E[X | \mathcal{G}_2 | \mathcal{G}_1 ]] = E[X | \mathcal{G}_1].$$
The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ alone is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of the one generated by $X,Y$, so the above property applies.

Assume that $E[D | XY] = E[D | X]$. Then,
\begin{align*}
E[YD | X] &= E[E[YD | XY] | X] \\
&= E[Y E[D | XY] | X] \\
&= E[Y E[D | X] | X] \\
&= E[D | X] E[Y|X].
\end{align*}
The first equality follows by the property, the second equality by measurability of $Y$ with respect to $\sigma(X,Y)$, the third by the conditional independence hypothesis, and the fourth by measurability of $E[D|X]$ with respect to $\sigma(X).$

The reverse direction is similar.